# How to prevent Page-break in <th> element when converting xml to html to pdf

Tags: html, css, pdf, xslt

I'm using XSLT to convert XML code into HTML so I can then convert it into a PDF to be downloaded. I'm using CSS in the XSLT to code the HTML so when the XML runs through the XSLT it comes out as perfectly costumized HTML code which I then convert into PDF.

All the code is divided into Tables , and I want to prevent the  elements in the code to page-break. It looks great on html only ,because it's not divided into pages, but when I convert it into PDF the problems start to show up , and a lot of  tags which provide the Title of the table are cut in half and shown in different pages. Like this

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZiTuW.jpg

As you can see the "Acontecimentos Especiais" title is divided into 2 different pages.

I've tried to use all the page-breaks inside CSS like :

-page-break-inside: avoid;

-page-break-before: avoid;

-page-break-after: avoid;

I've tried using them in the different CSS tags, i've tried them in the th tag and it doesn't work. I've tried them inside the table tag and it does work but the PDF is almost 25 pages long , and this just creates a LOT of white space between tables so it can fit the full table inside the page and That's makes things even worse.

I've also tried to use br tags to create spaces before the tables , but since they are "generated" and can have a random amount of rows depending on the XML , it's impossible to predict when a br will be needed. this also creates more problems than it helps.

I've tried putting div tags around the tables and using page-breaks but that also didn't do anything.

I'm lost on what to try after this since HTML is not a language I've worked with before.

All the tables have the same CSS:

Which is :

```
  <style>
  table.TabelaRatingDin {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 700px;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  }

  table.TabelaRatingDin th {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 6px;
  font-size: 10px;
  background-color: #4286f4;
  color: white;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  </style>
```

I just want the title of the table to not split into 2 different pages. It's fine if the content of the actual table is divided , just not the title.

Comment: So which approach/tool do you use to convert the HTML to PDF? If the HTML/CSS is fine in the browser (also there in print preview?) then it seems your tool to convert the HTML to PDF doesn't take the CSS or at least some of it into account.

Comment: I'm using Nreco HTML-to-PFD converter to do it. The Code looks fine in HTML because it's not divided into pages like it needs to be when converted to PDF , in HTML its just a huge browser page with all the content , but when it converts into PDF the fact that there are pages screws up the tables, everything else (all the css ) is perfect and works .

Comment: Well, desktop browsers like Chrome or Firefox for sure offer a print preview and/or print function to test whether HTML/CSS looks fine on paged media. For the rest I guess it is not a XSLT problem but rather a question about that tool you use, don't know it, check whether they have some support forum or offer support here on StackOverflow if you tag your question with a tag dedicated to that tool.

Comment: As for your CSS code, I don't think the relevant property names start with a dash so `-page-break-inside` should be `page-break-inside`.